# Have a way to get JavaScript value to CSS - root ? as default value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get length of html ul from Javascript as below (in my example) and passing it inside CSS :root selector.

I am not sure if it possible so I ask for it and hope so..

```js
    const elements = document.querySelector('ul');
    const length = elements.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
```

```css
:root{
  length: (JavaScript Value);
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>

<ul>
```

Inside `:root` should be `length: 5;` - (Receive that value from Javascript)

```
    :root{
      length: (JavaScript Value);
    }
```

Thanks for helping guys, Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.. If you want to dynamically add something to `:root` selector with some JS values you can do:

```
const elements = document.querySelector('ul');
const length = elements.getElementsByTagName('li').length;

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--var', `rgb(${length * 10}, 0, 0)`);
```

Comment: I hope it possible if not this ok too, Thanks for your fast answer